# Assembler printf function strange behavior

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, printf, ida

I've opened a simple Hello World program in `IDA` (Pro 7.5) like that:

```
    global  _main
    extern  _printf

    section .text
_main:
    push    message
    call    _printf
    add     esp, 4
    push    message2
    call    _printf
    add     esp, 4
    ret
message:
    db  'Hello, World 1', 0xD, 0xA, 0 
message2:
    db  'Hello, World 2', 0xD, 0xA, 0
```

Now i've made a simple `detour` - moved the `code` and `data` definition to the unused end of the `code` segment like this:

```
str1  db 'Hello, World1',0Dh,0Ah,0
                                         ; DATA XREF: .text:detour↓o
str2  db 'Hello, World2',0Dh,0Ah,0
                                         ; DATA XREF: .text:00404057↓o
str3  db 'Hello, World3',0Dh,0Ah,0
                                         ; DATA XREF: .text:00404064↓o↓o
      db    0
      db    0
 ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

 detour:                                 ; CODE XREF: .text:_main↑j
   push    offset str1     ; "Hello, World 1\r\n"
   call    _printf
   add     esp, 4
   push    offset str2     ; "Hello, World 2\r\n"
   call    _printf
   add     esp, 4
   push    offset str3     ; "Hello, World 3\r\n"
   call    _printf
   add     esp, 4
   jmp     go_back
```

Leaving in the `main` function only the `jmp` code like that:

```
_main:                                 
  jmp detour
go_back:                              
  retn
```

And this yeiled me a problem. The output of the patched program is :

```
Hello, World1

Hello, World2

Hello, World3

ABh@@Hello, World2

Hello, World3

ABh@@Hello, World3

ABh@@
```

Instead just:

```
Hello, World 1
Hello, World 2
Hello, World 3
```

Where do that extra 3 lines an empty rows

```
ABh@@Hello, World2

Hello, World3

ABh@@Hello, World3

ABh@@
```

come from?

Answer (score 1):

Printf prints strings until it finds a zero symbol.

Your original strings are zero terminated (0 at the end):

```
db  'Hello, World 1', 0xD, 0xA, 0
```

The new one, except str3, are not:

```
str1  db 'Hello, World 1',0Dh,0Ah
str2  db 'Hello, World 2',0Dh,0Ah
str3  db 'Hello, World 3',0Dh,0Ah
      db    0
```

Thus the first printf call prints all 3 strings, the second str2 and str3, and the third str3.

Comment: I've updated the code as You suggested friend but now i get even more bizarre result. Look for my updated question above.

Comment: Can You please answer my updated question?

Comment: IDA shows correct strings as comments of pushes (e.g. "Hello, World 1\r\n"). Statically it seems correct. Can you run the program in a debugger and check the contents of pushed strings? I have the feeling this is due to relocations and ASLR.

Comment: When the image is loaded at an address different from the base one, the image loader will update the code with relocation data. When you open your image in some Pe viewer, can you see a .reloc section?

Comment: Why do You say that image is loading at an address different from the base one? I haven't changed the `main` function location comparing the original. Only the code at `detour` label is relocated...

Comment: When ASLR is enabled in your OS, which is by default,  your OS can load your entire binary everytime at a different address.

Comment: What do relocation have to do with that code and is there a way to turn off the ASLR?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228671/discussion-between-nevilad-and-daros911).